# error Geolocalización en Background de Android

Tags: angular, ionic, geolocalización, capacitor

Llevo más de una semana dándole vueltas a un problema que tenemos con la APP (Runnea) en android.

Cuando la aplicación se pasa a un segundo plano android mata el watch position y dejo de capturar la posición del usuario por lo que perdemos el tracking.

Esto solo pasa en modo ahorro de energía, pero he visto que otras aplicaciones si que siguen trackeando.

Usamos Angular, iOnic y capacitor.
Los plugins de capacitor para localización y he probado con el listener de state de App o de ionic native.

Cualquier detalle que veáis que se necesite comentad porfa, porque me esta volviendo loco este asunto.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Asumo que están usando este plugin https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/background-task

Comment: he probado con ese a junto al geolocation de capacitor también. En general he probado creo que casi todos los plugins de localización y bg de npm y cap.

Comment: Agrega el código que haz realizado por favor para revisar, saludos.

Comment: @Elenasys es un buen cristo de código, al total serán como unas 500 lineas solo para la localización. En primer plano no hay problema, en segundo no funciona nada de lo que haya intentado.

Comment: Hola, no tienes que agregar todo el código de tu proyecto, solo lo esencial, por ejemplo como obtienes la geolocalización y como tienes configurado el servicio si es que usas alguno para esto.

Answer (score 2):

Leyendo la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) sobre los límites de geolocalización con ahorro de energía.

Como se menciona, a partir de Android 8, las aplicaciones en segundo plano solo pueden pedir la ubicación unas pocas veces por hora. Pero la clave está en que el sistema considere que tu aplicación está en primer plano.

En este sentido, se menciona que se considera que una aplicación está en primer plano si:

- Tienes una `Activity` visible.
- Tienes un servicio en primer plano.

Tu mejor opción sería, por tanto, crear un servicio **en primer plano**, para que incluso si tu aplicación no está visible, se considere que está en primer plano.

Lo haces mediante el método `startForegroundService`, cuya documentación está [aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)).

Answer (score 0):

No sé si esto te ayudará...

"Android, a fin de preservar la duración de la batería, configura los límites de ubicación en segundo plano en dispositivos que ejecutan Android 8.0 (nivel  26 de API) y versiones posteriores. En estas versiones de Android, si la app se ejecuta en segundo plano, puede recibir actualizaciones de ubicación solo algunas veces por hora."

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor compartir la fuente de esta información?

Comment: Sí, al final de esta página. https://developer.android.com/training/location/background?hl=es-419

Comment: El problema es que ante la misma situación apps como Strava SI que estan haciendo el tracking...

Answer (score 0):

no se si te será de ayuda, pero me pasó algo similar con el audio de un reproductor en segundo plano. Para mi, la solución fue crear un servicio para que Android no "mate" el proceso de segundo plano (aunque el usuario ponga el modo ahorro de energía):

```
    /*----------------
    BACKGROUND SERVICE
    ----------------*/
    private fun startService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, RadioBackgroundService::class.java)
        startService(serviceIntent)
    }

    private fun stopService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, RadioBackgroundService::class.java)
        stopService(serviceIntent)
    }
```

Dentro de la clase del servicio (**RadioBackgroundService** en mi caso), se debe ejecutar el proceso que no quieres que "corte" Android al entrar en background. Esta clase debe extender de la clase **Service** (class RadioBackgroundService**: Service()**...). Dentro de la clase debe estar la siguiente función:

```
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
```

Aparte de esta función, puedes usar todo el ciclo de vida de una actividad (onCreate, onDestroy...) para hacer lo que desees.

Por otro lado, no olvides declarar el servicio en el archivo manifest de tu proyecto.

```
    <service android:name=".services.RadioBackgroundService" />
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Un saludo!